# Using script and style tags in ASP.net MVC views?

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net-mvc

Is it a good practice to use `<script></script>` and `<style></style>` tags in MVC views? For example please consider the below code snippet in the simple view example provided with it.
    
        function myFunction() {
            //do something here
            return false;
        }
    
    
        .myCssClass{ color:red }

```
@model JavaScript_CSS_Test.Models.Employee

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Employee</legend>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunction() {
        //do something here
        return false;
    }
</script>
<style type="text/css">
    .myCssClass{ color:red }
</style>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")

}
```

Comment: There is no clear yes/no answer to this question. It depends on the nature of your application and it's usually a matter of personal preference.

Comment: Purists: Never, Pragmatics: Whenever it's appropriate.

Comment: Can lead to hard-to-maintain code if you use server-side code in your javascript.  Then when you decide to move them out, it all stops working (ref: 100s of SO questions on why js with razor tags don't work...)

Comment: Thanks for your quick replies haim770 & freedomn-m. I have updated the question with more details & really appreciate if you could comment on it. :)

Comment: In the updated question - the `<script>` tag should be in the `@section Scripts` so that it appears in the correct place in the page, but it's still personal or company specific.  You're not using js namespaces so there could be an issue if you include all your js files in your bundle, but not if you only include page specific per page.